# .bat rename files in folders/sub-folders to specific name

Tags: file, batch-file, directory, rename

I need a .bat file that can go into a folder with many sub-folders and rename every .iso file to "Game.iso". I had a way to do it but I cant seem to find it anymore and I lost the damn file :(.

Example:
-Main DIR
--A
---file name.iso
--B
---file name.iso
--Z
---file name.iso

What I want to be like when I run .bat file:
-Main DIR
--A
---game.iso
--B
---game.iso
--Z
---game.iso

That is really my main concern. That would be super amazing and I would appreciate it tremendously.

Comment: While I was looking and serching because I needed this done asap. I found a script to edit file extension from HTML to HTM, I edited it a bit because it seemed very easy to edit, and I got it working :) for /r %%x in (*.iso) do ren "%%x" game.iso

Answer (score 3):

Simple:

```
for /r %%a in (*.iso) do (
ren "%%~a" "%%~paGame.iso"
)
```

And that should work. Simply run it from the `Main Dir`

Comment: +1, I would ditch the parens and make it a one liner :-) Of course your code only works properly if no folder has more than one .iso file within it. But that is an inherent issue with the question as stated.

Comment: OK so it did not work :*(. I think what DBENHAm mentioned about not more than 1 file in each folder might have caused it not to work because I do have some folders with more than 1 file. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there another way of doing this so it works with more than 1 file per folder? Much thanks! :)

Comment: @juan71287 - you tell us. What do you want when you have multiple .iso files in one folder? You can't solve a problem if you don't define it properly.